# No sound from build-in speakers

Tags: drivers, sound

i've just installed elementary os on my laptop as my only os and i get no sond from the built-in speakers. But the sound works perfectly in my wireless earbuds. I think it's a problem of drivers because I've tried several linux distros on this laptop and all have the same issue. I am very new to linux so any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You may have to install it, but open `pavucontrol` and poke around inside that to see if the internal speakers are muted. To install, it's `sudo apt install pavucontrol` and then just `pavucontrol` in the terminal once it is installed. It may be already installed.

Comment: I've installed it. Checked, the audio is not muted, in the "output" option I only see "dummy output", I've clicked a random video on youtube and it shows that the sound-bar is moving, but in reality I don't hear any sound

Comment: For future reference, checking to see if it's muted is a good first step in debugging this problem. You can next try `sudo alsa force-reload` and then rebooting. It may appear to hang, so give it like 5 minutes and then press CTRL + C to stop it.